# Cannot read property 'employee_name' of undefined

Tags: api, postman

Im using Postman platform for testing API. I'm actually new to Postman. So, Currently testing dummy APIs, where i fetched the GET response result from the URI

- http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees , when i add validation points :
  specifying test description as "name" See below

var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);

tests["name"] = response.data[2].employee_name == "Ashton Cox";

Test operation successfully passed. But when using specific id in the URI link

- http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/5
  with same validations points as above, i'm getting response as TypeError: Cannot read property 'employee_name' of undefined, below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: What's the response body? You're also using the older sandbox syntax here, are you following an old tutorial?

Comment: i beg my part i attached a wrong screenshot, edited, yes response body status is OK, not sure but was 1yrs old.

Comment: @Danny Dainton please let me know if there modification in the syntax

Comment: Why do you have the `[4]` there? It's just an object not an array. The first request looks like it's getting all the results so it probably is an array. This is just getting a single user. Remove that `[4]` and keep the rest.

Comment: The `JSON value check` snippet listed on the right of the sandbox will show you the syntax.

Comment: @Danny Dainton thats node address/index number there are many objects with same name "id" in the data, i've checked it in JSONpath extension.                                        for ex.      .data[4].employee_name   now, here i believe 4 the index of the data with id = 4 & employee name is Airi Satou

Comment: Theres only a single object in `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct reference and syntax would look like this:

```
pm.test("Check User", () => {
  const responseJson = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(responseJson.data.employee_name).to.eql("Airi Satou");
});
```

Comment: it works, but is there any alternate code, i mean code is a little lengthy, reason i have no prior base of javascript, my core programming is in python only

Comment: You could remove the variable assignment line and just have `pm.response.json().data.employee_name` and put the test on a single line. Or you could use the wrong syntax, like what you were doing.  The tool your using is a JavaScript based tool.

Comment: that's pretty much right, you can close this ticket now, oh & lastly above syntax also works, thanks